# Please give a quick example how to simlate BorderLayout with MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout, border-layout

I wish `WEST` and `EAST` fractions of layout be of constant width. How to setup this with `MigLayout`?

**UPDATE**

The following code does not resize like border layout:

```
package testing.Test_MigLayout_01;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class App201210042244 
{

private class JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    {
        setLayout(new MigLayout());

        add(new JButton("1"), "dock east, width 120");
        add(new JButton("2"), "west");
        add(new JButton("3"), "center");
        add(new JButton("4"), "north");
        add(new JButton("5"), "south");

    }

}

public App201210042244() {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
                jFrame.pack();
                jFrame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
}


public static void main( String[] args )
{
   new App201210042244();
}
}
```

The size of window internals remains constant:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
panel.add(new JButton("1"), "dock east, width 120");
panel.add(new JButton("2"), "west");
panel.add(new JButton("3"), "center");
panel.add(new JButton("4"), "north");
panel.add(new JButton("5"), "south");
```

The *dock* keyword can be omitted.

UPDATE:

If you want *all* your components to expand when the window is resized:

```
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill"));
panel.add(new JButton("1"), "dock east, width 120");
panel.add(new JButton("2"), "west");
panel.add(new JButton("3"), "center, grow");
panel.add(new JButton("4"), "north");
panel.add(new JButton("5"), "south");
```